# Finding the index values for a combination of vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, dplyr, subset

In my reproducible data below, I wonder how to find the **index values** for elements from the one-on-one matched vectors `rs` & `hat` that satisfy the following condition:

`rs < -1.96` OR `rs > 1.96` elements  whose corresponding `hat` elements are `hat` > `max_hat` elements

Is this possible to plot (using `text()`) the index values next to its plotted circle in the plot below?

```
x <- readRDS(url("https://github.com/rnorouzian/s/raw/main/cooks.rds"))
hat <- readRDS(url("https://github.com/rnorouzian/s/raw/main/hat.rds"))
rs <- readRDS(url("https://github.com/rnorouzian/s/raw/main/rstudent.rds"))$z


plot(hat, rs, cex = 0.2+3*sqrt(x), pch = 19)

max_hat <- boxplot.stats(hat, coef = 2)$stats[5]
```

[image]

Comment: @akrun, the answers are not complete though, they don't work with `res2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both conditions define logical vectors so AND them and get `which` indices they correspond to. Then plot.
I have added color to make the text labels more obvious.

```
max_hat <- boxplot.stats(hat, coef = 2)$stats[5]

i <- abs(rs) > 1.96  # abs() because +/-1.96 are 
                     # symmetric values
j <- hat > max_hat
k <- which(i & j)

plot(hat, rs, cex = 0.2+3*sqrt(x), pch = 19)
text(hat[k], rs[k], labels = names(k), pos = 2, col = "red")
```

[image]